# Connect Individual Email Results from Marketing Cloud to Campaign in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign, campaign-member, sales-cloud

this is our situation:

1. We are using Marketing Cloud as a tool to send out emails to customers.
2. Sales Cloud is being used to store the customer data and perform all the reporting etc.

We are now thinking about how to get the data about sends from Marketing to Sales Cloud. As per "standard" (the managed package) the Individual Email Results object seems to be the way to go which would satisfy the requirement of having the email events in Salesforce Sales Cloud.

However, we want to have an aggregation / grouping of those results on a campaign. E.g. we are sending out a birthday email using a journey for example and we would like to both know whether the individual contact responded to it and also how many of the "campaign members" did respond to it.

Is there a way to implement this using the more or less standard functionality? Do you have any experience on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a standard functionality for what you want to achieve. It's called Campaign Member Integration. You find the documentation here: [Salesforce Help](http://mc_co_campaign_member_integration.htm&type=5)

This allows Marketing Cloud to update campaign member status based on interaction with your email while still allowing custom statuses for your invitation management.

So I think this should do the job you described.

Comment: That sounds interesting, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the standard Campaign Member Integration allows only to update the Status of the Campaign Member.

But apparently, what you are looking for is to have a link between the Individual Email Result (IER) and the Campaign Member. In the IER, there is a field called "et4ae5__CampaignMemberId__c" that is created by SFMC and that might be the one to use to link both objects.